# Getting "Dispatching event 'DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument' failed" error when using jsdom

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, jsdom

I'm considering using JSDom for a project that requires scraping a site.
I started by trying an Amazon page. Here's a sample code:

```
jsdom.env(url, ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"], function(errors, window) {
    console.log(errors);
    var $ = window.$,
        results = parseResultsPage($);
    //do some stuff
    window.close();
});
```

At first, I had an `if(errors.length > 0) ...` clause, but it turns out, `errors` is always full. Even though the scraping itself works, and I get all the results I need, I always get:

```
[ { type: 'error',
    message: 'Dispatching event \'DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument\' failed',
    data: { error: [Object], event: [Object] } } ]
```

This means I cannot test for errors effectively. Simply ignoring this error feels unsafe to me.

Any suggestions? Could this be an Amazon-related issue? (they're using jQuery 1.2.6 on their pages)

**Update**:
Submitted issue on JSDom github page ([link](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/687)).

Comment: Ran into the exact same problem.  I ended up using [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) + [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) instead.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after a debug session using node-inspector, I managed to single out the piece of code on the Amazon page that throws that error.
It's a CSS rule inside a long inline `<style>` element, that JSDom does not know how to handle:

```
<style type="text/css">
...
.cust-rec-aui-button @-moz-document url-prefix(){
    .cust-rec-aui-button .a-button .a-button-text{
        line-height:29px
    }

    .cust-rec-aui-button .a-button.a-button-small .a-button-text{
        line-height:21px
    }

}
...
</style>
```

At first, I thought it was a CSS syntax error (though JSDom is not supposed to throw an exception for those), but then I found some sources ([here's one](http://blog.justagirl.us/2012/05/07/firefox-user-content-css/%29%3a)) that say this is perfectly legal.

So, after conferring with the developers of JSDom ([see issue on Github](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/687) to get the whole correspondence, along with code that reproduces the issue), it has been declared a bug, and hopefully will get fixed!